# Does it matter what kind of monarch I am?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-battle-warriors-way

My advisor just asked me what sort of monarch I want to be now that I have conquered the world. My choices were "famous" or "mighty" - does this choice have any actual in-game consequences?